# check user credentials in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Student model which has a one to one field with the default user model.

I have a url like example.com/studentid where student id is an integer value.

I want to know how I can check whether the studentid in the url is equal to the studentid of the person who has logged in?

this is in order to ensure that the person who has logged in can only view his own personal profile and not any other students profile, even if he randomly changes the value of studentid in the url.

Comment: You don't need to use a `student_id` in the url if this is the case as you always have access to the current user through `request.user`. Your url can just be `/student/profile/` and your view will be able to render just the relevant data for the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its simple:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

student = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=student_id, user__id=request.user.id)
```

This will raise `404` Exception if user trying to access other user profile or action.

As `Timmy O'Mahony` suggested you even don't need to disclose student id in the url (if it is not necessary). Just  get the currently logged in user in `request.user` and then use that to get the student profile:

```
def my_student_view(request):
    user = request.user
    student = Student.objects.get(user__id=user.id)
```